# Spring @JdbcTest tries to create other beans

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I try to test my repository class but when I try to test it, I got Application Failed exception.

WebApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("co.mainpackage")
public class WebApplicationConfig
{
   ...
       @Bean
    public StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate(LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory)
    {
        StringRedisTemplate template = new StringRedisTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        return template;
    }
}
```

KeywordRepository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class KeywordRepository
{
  private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
  ...
}
```

KeywordRepositoryTest:

```
@JdbcTest
@Import({KeywordRepository.class})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase( replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Sql("/data/keyword.sql")
public class KeywordRepositoryTest
{
    @Autowired
    private KeywordRepository keywordRepository;
    ...
}
```

And error says:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'otherBean'
...
```

Here, I should use `@ComponentScan` because I have multi-module project...
I need `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` because I use embedded-test database.

Comment: The problem is your `@ComponentScan`. If your `@SpringBootApplication` class is in the same (root) package it doesn't need this, if you really need it, move it to a separate `@Configuration` class.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your answer. When I moved it to separate `@Configuration` file, I got another error like: `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource'...`

Comment: The problem is we have only part of a the whole picture. Basically all your `@Bean` methods and other customizations should be in separate config classes, else those beans will be started as well, requiring additional setup.